# TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

Tags: json, python-3.x, pymongo, bson

I am trying to write data into `pymongo` and this the TypeError that I am getting. The Type for `mydict1` is `List`. Do I have to convert my data into `json` or `bson` before I write it to `pymongo`? Kindly help.
Thanks.

```py
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as poly 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pymongo
import json
import pandas as pd

 
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\polynomial\points.csv')
print(df)

x= np.array(df['Wavelength(A)'].tolist())
x= np.divide([299792.458], x)
y= np.array(df['Level(A)'].tolist())
x_trimmed = np.delete(x, np.where(y < 1e-4))
y_trimmed = np.delete(y, np.where(y < 1e-4))
test= poly.fit(x_trimmed, y_trimmed, 10)
print (test)

list1= test.convert().coef
print (list1)
print (len(list1))
#print (type(list1))
to_list= list1.tolist()
#print(to_list)
#data_format= json.dumps(to_list)
l = len(to_list)
#print (l)
mydict1= []
for i in range(l):
    mydict = { "a"+str(i) : to_list[i] }
    mydict1.append(mydict)
print (mydict1)


myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]
mycol = mydb["coefficients"]
x = mycol.insert_one(mydict1)
```

This is mydict1=

```py
[{'a0': -2.3373800910827825e+34}, {'a1': 1.2084654060419298e+33}, {'a2': -2.811587585787653e+31}, {'a3': 3.876370042231405e+29}, {'a4': -3.507261557232249e+27}, {'a5': 2.1759768836934694e+25}, {'a6': -9.37514311649608e+22}, {'a7': 2.7697765301392782e+20}, {'a8': -5.370081422614614e+17}, {'a9': 616983041924503.2}, {'a10': -318990754999.1472}]
```

Comment: You need to edit your question to add the code that is updating the database.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that MongoDB's [insert_one](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update%20one#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one) method inserts a single document that is represented by a dictionary, not a list.

The possible solutions are:

- use [`insert_many`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html?highlight=update%20one#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) instead. In this case, you will have every list item as a separate mongodb document
- make a dict with your list values. You can use something like `{"items": mydict1}`, or `reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, mydict1)` depending on the document structure that will be better for your needs